# Safari: how to use tab overview entirely via keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

On my system, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is bound to the menu item View / Show Tab Overview.  It's pretty nice.  There is a search field in the top right that gets focus, so it's very convenient to search for a tab from there: Just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and then a search string.

But I can't figure out how to actually select a tab without using the mouse.  I'm a keyboard aficionado who likes to do things via the keyboard, and having to move the hand over to the touchpad kind of interferes.

I've tried just hitting Return when only one tab is left, I've tried cursor-down, I've tried <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, I've tried tab, ...

Answer (score 0):

My Safari 17.1 is bit deferent

To enter the Tab Overview it uses

<kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>CMD</kbd>
<kbd>backslash</kbd>

To find specific tab, I type the first letter or first two letters

To move mouse pointer with keyboard

I use settings in accessibility and turn on pointer control with keyboard as described in [Move pointer with keyboard](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-the-pointer-using-mouse-keys-mh27469/mac)

Comment: Is moving the mouse pointer with the keyboard a convenient way to select one of the tabs found after entering a search string?

Comment: convenient would be using the mouse, but you asked for keyboard been 'keyboard aficionado `

Comment: YOU COULD USE THIS TO FIND SOMETHING FOR YOU https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Comment: Thank you @Ruskes, I was hoping that the cursor keys can choose between the different tabs, or the tab key perhaps.  I have never tried to control the mouse pointer with the keyboard, and so I didn't know if it is better than using the mouse.  I don't like having to use the mouse, but if the alternative is worse...  I guess I will try it and report back.